# Angular 2: nesting child components flexible

Tags: angular

I searched for an option to include html tags in a child component from parent side, like

Parent component:

```
<child><button>+</button></child>
```

Child component:

```
<form>
  <input />
  <!-- insert button here -->
</form>
```

I know that it is possible in react, but how can I do it in Angular 2?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the working demo on Plunker I made:

{{ [HERE](https://plnkr.co/edit/39iIg1V8T0UuSFAAKhSs?p=preview) }}

I simply sent  using the `@Input` decorator this simple piece of HTML `<b>This bold html text is coming from the parent</b>` as a string and then I rendered the html using the `[innerHTML]` attribute with property binding.

and here is a snapshot from the Plunker how the bold text is rendered:
[image]